# Exporting multiple excel sheets into seperate PDFs spits out Runtime Error 5

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation

I need to creat a macro, which exports each worksheet into a seperate PDF with the name of the worksheet as the new filename of the PDF.
When I run the macro it spits out Runtime Error 5: Invalid Procedure call or argument

Her's my code:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim Folder_Path As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Ordner zum Speichern der PDFs auswählen"
    
    If .Show = -1 Then Folder_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
    
End With

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Folder_Path & Application.PathSeparator & sh.Name & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
Next

MsgBox "Fertig!"

End Sub
```

It seems to run into the Error on the ExportAsFixedFormat action, but I don't see why.

Comment: Your code should work as it is. Does it export any sheet and raise the respective error for a specific one (sheet)? If not, is your first sheet protected, hidden? When stopped on error, moving the cursor over `sh.name`, what does it show? Is anything unusual with the respective sheet?

Comment: @FaneDuru It really was a hidden sheet. Thanks for the tip. Now it exports all the sheets but still runs in the same runtime error 5. If i hover over the sh.name it shows sh.Name = "Tabelle24" which as far as i can tell inst the name of any of my sheets.

Comment: Can't you test (in code) if hidden to unhide it and back to initial visibility status after exporting? In fact I will post a piece of code adapting yours to do it. No more than two, tree minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code. It previously check the sheet visibility and according to its status, from this point of view, unhide, export and hide it as it initially was:

```
Sub Makro1()
 Dim Folder_Path As String

 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Ordner zum Speichern der PDFs auswählen"
    
    If .Show = -1 Then Folder_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
 End With

 Dim sh As Worksheet, shVis As XlSheetVisibility, boolVis As Boolean

 For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With sh
        If .Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then   'if it is hidden
            shVis = .Visible                            'memorise its visibility
            sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible: boolVis = True 'make it visible and boolVis True
        End If
        'export the (visible) sheet:
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=Folder_Path & _
                Application.PathSeparator & sh.name & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
                
        If boolVis Then .Visible = shVis: boolVis = False 'change back the initial visibility and reinitialize boolVis as False
    End With
 Next

MsgBox "Fertig!"

End Sub
```

Not tested, but it should solve the hidden sheet issue.

If still a problem appear, please identify it doing the same examination, moving the cursor over the respective sheet name and see what is it about. If a protected sheet, for instance, the code can be adapted to also overpass such a situation...

Comment: Is there an option  instead of `boolvis` , I mean to add the hidden sheets to an Array or a collection and change back at end of code ?

Comment: @Waleed  It is possible (theoretically), but using **two array** and you will not gain too much. I mean, the 'problematic' hidden sheets can be `xlSheetHidden` or `xlSheetVeryHidden` and you must also keeping this information somewhere. Then, hiding is done almost instant, not triggering any event (especially `Calculation`) which need changings, formulas updating etc.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that one of your sheets is empty

Comment: In such a case the error message should be different. Something like 'didn't find anything to print'...

Comment: @FaneDuru I think that massage will throw in Excel application environment, not in VBA editor environment.

Comment: If such an error is raised, the respective code line will be yellow and a 'Run-time error' (I think `1004`)  is raised. Raised by VBA... It ca be handled in code, but we firstly need to know what problem does the respective sheet have, I think.